# Remove DRM From a WMV file I own

Tags: wmv, drm

Alright, first, let me explain. I purchased some content through Microsoft's Zune/Xbox Video service, and man that was a mistake. After trying several times to get the video to play, I received an error along the lines of "out of licenses." Lucky for me, I was able to recover the file I was looking for off of a backup, but now I'm having problems playing it. It works fine in Windows Media Player, but not in Zune or Xbox Video (on Windows 8). I contacted Zune's customer support, and of course they couldn't help me.

So, I legally own the content, I just want to be able to play it where I want to play it. It's ridiculous that I can't. I know there are ways to do this out there, I just can't figure it out (I keep getting directed to this piece of junk thing called Almedia, which kind of seems to work, but was only putting out audio in the demo version).

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should talk to Bruce Willis...

Comment: yea, lol...this whole horrid DRM thing makes no sense anyway. Here I am, a legitimate consumer who spent way too much money to watch Doctor Who on my computer, and I'm having this experience from hell. I could go to The Pirate Bay and have the damn thing in about 10 minutes. DRM never, ever stops the pirates. It just hurts consumers.

Comment: Doesn't Zune and Xbox Video more or less contain all the features of Windows Media Player. Have you tried software like VLC? What market place did you purchase this file at?  I will flag this question as a favorite so you can update and provide more information.

Comment: I bought it off of Xbox Video/Zune Video (they're the same thing). And it has most features, but not all. I'd like to able to play it wherever I want though. IF I try to open it in VLC it crashes the program.